# How to fetch content from other websites

Tags: javascript, security, xss

There are so many public websites running which display entire website in some kind of frame in their site.
For example:- Check out proxy websites in which there is a frame and a box in which we enter the URL. After typing URL, these sites fetch whole html page and render in their box. I want to learn how do they perform this. Don't they face issue of XSS? Please help me understand and learn. :)

Comment: One of the examples you can check out is http://zend2.com

Answer (score 0):

You could try, for example, the `urllib` module in python to scrape websites given their url, but be careful about things you shouldn't do. Always be aware of the terms and conditions. Remember, with great power comes great responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

Restrictions against cross-site scripting (XSS) are only relevant specifically for JavaScript.  The issue is that without restrictions, arbitrary executable code can be injected into your web site.  There are many ways of linking content from other's sites to yours; this idea is one of the fundamental ideas behind the WWW. 
One of many possibilities is they are using [Framing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framing_%28World_Wide_Web%29), for example with iframes: `<iframe src="someone-elses-website.com">`.

Comment: Thanks paul..I will be checking it too in some course of time..thanks once again

Comment: Paul Iframe thing is not working. I have tried it and I am getting the following error: Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options. I don't know why this happened..